# Scraped Data not Printing- Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup

Scraping data from a html file and when i run my app the default screen just appears. Dont tell me to read the jsoup doc please, read it all already. Anyone any idea how to get it to print on the screen?

```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
   import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
   import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
   import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
   import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        File input = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Mobile Newest\\JSoup\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\filename.html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
        Elements tableElements = doc.select("td");
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        for (Element td : tableElements) {
            textView.setText(td.text());
            System.out.println(td.text());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //System.out.println("Testing");
}
```

}
Activity Main

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?  attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"          android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Content Main

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="Hello World!" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Its the main activity screen, it just says "Hello World" instead of the data i have scraped

Comment: post `activity_main`.

Comment: `content_main` main too. BTW I have already posted an answer. Check it.

Comment: Yeah added in the "TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);" just gotta an error with text_view and unused textView?

Comment: check the updated answer. That was an example. You need to define id for your view to get its reference.

Comment: `File input = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Mobile Newest\\JSoup\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\filename.html");` this seems to be a file on Desktop not mobile. So `input` doesn't exists. You can verify that by `input.exists()`

Comment: i put in input.exists(), just gave me an error, the file is the project folder on the desktop

Answer (score 0):

As per comments on question:

If you want to show any message to `TextView`, then get it's reference and then set text to it.

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);

for (Element td : tableElements) {
   textView.setText(td.text());
}
```

Define an id for your `TextView` in `content_main`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: added this in, still not getting to print once i run the app on my phone

Comment: Is this printing `System.out.println(td.text())`?

Comment: If `System.out.println(td.text())` is not working then there is parsing problem. Not related to displaying it in `TextView`

Comment: any idea on a solution? so is it to do with my html?